# Why would my NSMutableDictionary be nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to store an array in a NSMutableDictionary. However the NSMutableDictionary is null after  i have set objects to it. Here is my code any help is appreciated:

```
NSMutableArray *arrTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dTemp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
STStockData *stockData = [[STStockData alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [_arrTickers count]; i++) {
    // get the ticker from its json form
    dTemp = [_arrTickers objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Ticker: %@",[dTemp objectForKey:@"ticker"]);
    // gets current data for ticker
    [arrTemp addObjectsFromArray:[stockData getCurrentStockDataForTicker:[dTemp objectForKey:@"ticker"]]];
    NSLog(@"Price %@",[arrTemp objectAtIndex:1]); // just to prove the array isnt nil.
    // adds it to the dictionary
    [_dStockData setObject:arrTemp forKey:[dTemp objectForKey:@"ticker"]];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary %@",_dStockData);
    // remove all objects so can reuse.
    [arrTemp removeAllObjects];
    dTemp = nil; // can't remove objects using [removeAllObjects] method. believe its due to it holding inside NSArrays which are immutable.

}
```

Here is the console output:

[image]

Comment: have you alloc init _dStockData dicationary?

Comment: look at this--> NSLog(@"Dictionary %@",_dStockData); Why Don`t you try NSLog(@"My Dict IS %@", dTemp); And then see what`s your Dictionary?

Comment: Sorry i should of said _dStockData is a property of the class. It is a NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize _dStockData

```
_dStockData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Comment: Yeah sorry i was waiting for it to allow me to.  @julie I'm still having problems by the end of the for loop when i print the dictionary it only prints the keys and not the arrays inside (outside for loop). However when i print the dictionary in the for loop it prints fine. Do you know why the arrays would be cleared from the _dStockData by the end of the for loop?

Comment: Sorted it. If you're interested it was to do with me removing all objects from arrTemp. NSMutableDictionarys hold pointers to objects so once i called [arrTemp removeAllObjects] it also removes all objects from the NSMutableDictionary. But thanks anyway @julie

Answer (score 0):

It is nil because use initialize stockData

```
STStockData *stockData = [[STStockData alloc] init];
```

and print _dStockData

```
NSLog(@"Dictionary %@",_dStockData);
```